# Vertical empty path is not vertical with package tkz-berge

Tags: tkz-berge

According to the manual, `\grEmptyPath` with `form=2` should draw a vertical path.  However, it seems that the path is just moved to the left some distance.  Is this an error in `tkz-berge`, or am I doing something wrong?  An example follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
          \grEmptyPath[RA=1]{4}
          \grEmptyPath[prefix=b,RA=1,RS=1]{4}
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \qquad
     \begin{tikzpicture}
          \grEmptyPath[form=2,RA=1]{4}
          \grEmptyPath[prefix=b,RA=1,RS=1]{4}
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Medina:  Item 2.2.3 of `tkz-berge-screen.pdf`.

Comment: Yes, I just saw it.

Comment: I am using MiKTeX 2.9, which comes with tkz-berge 1.00c (the CTAN version, I guess).  It seems that there is a newer (beta?) version of tkz-berge in its original site [http://www.altermundus.fr](http://www.altermundus.fr).  I did not tried it yet.

Comment: The `form` seems to refer to a way to align the vertices. I guess "vertical" refers to alignment of different layers and not necessarily to place  a single layer vertically. Look at this example: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Shade]
\SetVertexNoLabel
\grTriangularGrid[RA=2,form=1]{3}
\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
\grTriangularGrid[RA=2,form=2]{3}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=10cm]
\grTriangularGrid[RA=2,form=3]{3}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}` .

Comment: This is, however, mere speculation since I am not expert in Graph Theory and `tkz-berge` seems to implement some procedures from John C. Doyle.

Comment: @Medina:  In `tkz-berge`, the meaning of `form` depends on the macro that is being used.  So the behavior of `grTriangularGrid` could give no information about `grEmtpyPath`.  I noticed that item 2.2.3 of `tkz-berge-screen.pdf` shows an horizontal path where a vertical path is expected.  I think that this is because `form` is not working well in version 1.00c, since example #9 on page 10 of [http://www.altermundus.fr/pages/downloads/TKZdoc-berge.pdf](http://www.altermundus.fr/pages/downloads/TKZdoc-berge.pdf) actually shows a vertical path (each node above the previous one).

Comment: Yes, you're right. After seeing the results in the documentation you linked to, it's clear that it's a bug in the current version.